# regex node javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Need find all the text to "min" inclusive.

All online services and "subline text 3" are correct found, but the "match" returns null. Help me please

ps: sorry for my english

JavaScript:

```
var tmp = data.match(/(\[Rec\].+?),(.+?),(.+?),(\d+),((.|\n)*?min)/ig);
```

String:

```
[Rec] name,2016-01-13 00:51:22.447,2015-05-11 00:21:52.497,1,[ 2016.09.11 21:14:56 ] name > some text
[ 2016.09.11 21:19:36 ] name : some text
[ 2016.09.11 21:19:48 ] name : some text
[ 2016.09.11 21:20:07 ] name : some text

30 mins

[Rec] name,2016-09-10 13:55:23.117,2016-04-11 11:51:23.117,1,[ 2016.09.09 20:52:56 ] name > text
[ 2016.09.09 20:53:05 ] name : some text
[ 2016.09.09 20:53:43 ] name : some text
[ 2016.09.09 20:54:23 ] name : some text

40 minutes
```

**expected output:**

```
tmp[1] = [Rec] name
tmp[2] = 2016-01-13 00:51:22.447
tmp[3] = 2015-05-11 00:21:52.497
tmp[4] = 1
tmp[5] = [ 2016.09.11 21:14:56 ] name > some text [ 2016.09.11 21:19:36 ] name : some text [ 2016.09.11 21:19:48 ] name : some text [ 2016.09.11 21:20:07 ] name : some text
30 min
```

Comment: can you show us an example of expected output?

Comment: done, sry first use this site

Comment: You should never use `(.|\n)*?`, always replace with `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thx! its help !

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `Regex.exec(String)` instead of `String.match(Regex)`.

Here is a jsfiddle, open the console to see the output.

https://jsfiddle.net/qwaxhk1g/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is highly possible you also have carriage returns in your file, and `.` in JS regex does not match them. You should replace the `(.|\n)*?` with a much more efficient `[\s\S]*?` (or `[^]*?`, though it will only ever work in JS regex).

Also, you seem to need to access capturing group contents, and when you use `/g` modifier, you need to use run `RegExp#exec(String)` in a loop to grab all matches together with captures.

```js
var rx = /(\[Rec\].+?),(.+?),(.+?),(\d+),([\s\S]*?min)/ig;
var s = "[Rec] name,2016-01-13 00:51:22.447,2015-05-11 00:21:52.497,1,[ 2016.09.11 21:14:56 ] name > some text\n[ 2016.09.11 21:19:36 ] name : some text\n[ 2016.09.11 21:19:48 ] name : some text\n[ 2016.09.11 21:20:07 ] name : some text\n\n30 mins\n\n[Rec] name,2016-09-10 13:55:23.117,2016-04-11 11:51:23.117,1,[ 2016.09.09 20:52:56 ] name > text\n[ 2016.09.09 20:53:05 ] name : some text\n[ 2016.09.09 20:53:43 ] name : some text\n[ 2016.09.09 20:54:23 ] name : some text\n\n40 minutes";
while ((m=rx.exec(s)) !== null) {
  console.log("Current match:");
  console.log(m[1]);
  console.log(m[2]);
  console.log(m[3]);
  console.log(m[4]);
  console.log(m[5]);
}
```